# Why does this linear system have no solution?

Tags: linear-algebra

\begin{bmatrix}
-7 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 9 & -4 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}

I believe that this augmented matrix has infinitely many solutions but don't know why the answer says it has no solution.

Comment: Is that an augmented matrix? Thus the system **obviously** has solution: the trivial one...but not only that. Why don't you write down *the whole question*?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Are you sure the answer is "no solutions" and if so, are you sure the bottom right element is in fact a zero?

Comment: Is it the RREF of the augmented matrix?

Comment: @gimusi It isn't in RREF form.

Comment: Please show the initial equation system!

Comment: Did  the question actually ask whether there was a *unique* solution? If so, answer is no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has solutions $x=0,y=4t,z=9t.$

Answer (score 0):

If I interpret your question as $Ax=b$, where $b$ is a column vector and you append $A$ and $b$ and reduce it to the augmented matrix above. Then yes, the zero vector is a solution and in fact is has infinitely many solution.